# My row reduced form doesn't match the answer but seems valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Starting matrix:
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
    2  &3  &−4\\
    5  &2  &1\\
    1 &−6  &3\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
The answer I'm supposed to get:
$$
\text{Given} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 &3 &-4\\
    0 &-5.5 &11\\
    0 &0 &1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
However, the answer I get is:
$$
\text{Mine} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 &3 &-4\\
    0 &-5.5 &11\\
    0 &0 &-10\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
I did the following:

Added $-\frac52 R_1$ to $R_2$

Added $-\frac12 R_1$ to $R_3$

Added $-\frac{15}{11} R_2$ to $R_3$

Are any of those three invalid? Is there some rule about row reduction I missed that makes it so I need to figure out how to reduce that $-10$ to a $1$? I feel like it's got something to do with the $-4$ in $R_{1,3}$ but I fail to see why I would *need* to make that $-10$ a $1$...

The reason this bothers me is that I'm supposed to be using the combined elementary matrix as an answer, but my combined elementary matrix only differs in the $R_{3,1}$ location (mine is $-\frac12$ and theirs is $2.9091$, I still have no idea how they got that) so I get the question wrong. My question is basically how can they call mine wrong if both matrices are valid row reduced forms so both combined elementary matrices are valid?

Comment: Those are both valid; in either case, multiplying row 2 by $-2/11$ makes it prettier.

Comment: _Reduced_ row echelon form has 1s in the diagonal and is unique. Your matrix is in row echelon form, but not reduced row echelon form. Reduce your matrix further to see the equivalence!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of row echelon form, your answer is equivalent to the given answer. You just have to perform an additional row operation, that is multiply the third row by $-\frac1{10}$ to get the given answer.

In general, row echelon form is not unique. That is if two people work out the question together, comparing answers might not be that obvious.

Note that, however, reduced row echelon form is unique.

The reason you are marked wrong is not because of non-uniqueness of row echelon form. You made a computational mistake.

$$\left(-\frac{15}{11} \right)\left(-\frac52 \right)-\frac12 =\frac{32}{11} \approx2.9091$$

In fact, I don't think that is the answer that everyone has. I believe the grader was trying to tell you that, "hey, there is a mistake in this particular entry, here is the answer that you are supposed to obtain according to your row echelon form".

Comment: Sorry to trouble you but could you explain how you got to the 32/11 in that spot? When I multiply my three E matrices I get -1/2 in R3,1 and don't see why I would get 32/11? Am I making a dumb multiplication mistake?

Comment: let's try to debug this together. Let $E_1$ corresponds to $R_2  -\frac52R_1$ . Let $E_2$ corresponds to $R_3 -\frac12 R_1$. and Let $E_3$ corresponds to $R_3-\frac{15}{11}R_2$. You are supposed to compute $E_3E_2E_1$. Did you first compute $E_2E_1$?

Comment: Thank you for the help :D
Yeah, E2 E1 produces (can you even put matrices in comments? Hope this is legible) 
R1: 1,0,0 R2: -5/2,1,0 R3: -1/2,0,1

Comment: So far you are doing great with no mistake. awesome. Now let's multiply $E_3$ which corresponds to $R_3 - \frac{15}{11}R_2$. Your third row should be $ \begin{bmatrix} -\frac12 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} - \frac{15}{11}\begin{bmatrix} -\frac52 & 1  & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Alternatively,  by taking the third row of $E_3$ and multiply by the first column of $E_2E_1$, the $(3,1)$-entry is also equal to $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\frac{15}{11}  & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -\frac52 \\ -\frac12\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: So when I do what you say I get 32/11 as I should, but when I multiply the E matrices out I come up with my third row as -1/2,-15/11,1. It doesn't put 32/11 in R3,1?
Oh I see the problem! Stupid me forgot matrix multiplication is not commutative! THANK YOU omg

Comment: You mean as you multiply $E_3$ and $E_2E_1$ together? Where $E_3$ is on the left and $E_2E_1$ is on the right? can you show me your $E_3$ matrix? (in practice, we do not write our elementary matrices explicitly, but just for debugging and learning purpose now)

Comment: Yeah I had my left matrix as 
1, 0, 0;
-5/2, 1, 0;
-1/2, 0, 1; and my right matrix as 
1, 0, 0;
0, 1, 0;
0, -15/11, 1; but when I flip them I get the right answer with 32/11 in the R3,1 spot

Comment: $E_3E_2E_1$ is not equal to $E_2E_1E_3$. I think that is the mistake.
Remark: In general we do not multiply elementary matrices explicitly. We view $E_3E_2E_1=E_3(E_2(E_1I))$, we just perform row operations on the identity matrix. if you are familiar with big $O$ notation, the complexity of multiply $K$ elementary matrices is $O(kn)$ rather than $O(kn^2)$.

Comment: thank you so much man this was super helpful I apologize for taking so much of your time for something so dumb though

Comment: you are welcome. learning takes time. have fun learning.